# Copy row with 2 different values into same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble getting a record to be copied and inserted into the same table but with different values and based on two conditions.

What I so Far:

```
INSERT INTO Userdetails
(ID, Username, Firstname, Surname, Location, TimeAs)
SELECT ID, Username, Firstname, Surname, Location, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
Userdetails where Username = 'Harvard'; // and the latest date of the record
```

What I am trying to do is when a location is updated a new record with a new Timestamp and location with all the details of the old record (Firstname etc...) is inserted into the table, but keeping the old record.

If I just use the WHERE Username = I multiply the number of records each time the query is executed by 2x.

Sample Date:

```
Username | Firstname | Surname | Location | Last Updated

Harvard    David       Beckham   London    2017-05-08 12:11:00

Harvard    David       Beckham   Turkey    2017-05-08 12:14:00

Stanton    John        Smith     Paris     2017-05-08 11:24:00
 // This would be the result of the query, With a different timeStamp and Location but keeping the old record
Harvard    David       Beckham   Hong Kong    2017-05-08 12:20:00
```

What I would like it to do is Copy the latest record where the username = 'Harvard' but also look use the latest time and not just the Username, as this would create 2 records not just the 1 I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `GETDATE()` function instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in your SELECT.

Comment: I'd consider some table design changes. Why store same Username, Firstname, Surname, Location values over and over again?

Comment: Your question would make more sense (to me) if you provided sample data and desired results.  The first paragraph and second to last paragraph seem contradictory.

Comment: @jarlh Such as having a table that would hold only the latest location for each user? Deleting the current user then inserting a copy of the row with the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, you can simply use `top 1` with `order by`:

```
INSERT INTO Userdetails
(ID, Username, Firstname, Surname, Location, TimeAs)
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Username, Firstname, Surname, Location, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM Userdetails 
WHERE Username = 'Harvard'
ORDER BY TimeAs DESC;
```